# menu overlay - can't make content full height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make the inner content of a menu overlay take up full height so I can center the content in the middle of the page. I tried using height: 100% and also tried height: 100vh but no luck. It doesn't make because I'm using the same code in codepen and on codepen it works but not in my project on my laptop... very confused.

Here is the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/harp30/pen/yqLdWp?editors=0110

pug code:

```
#js-menu.menu
    .container
       .menu__content 
            ul.menu__list.menu__list--top
              li.menu__link
                a.link-anchor.active About us
              li.menu__link
                a.link-anchor Our Team
              li.menu__link
                a.link-anchor areas of practice
              li.menu__link
                a.link-anchor news &amp; media

            ul.menu__list.menu__list--bottom.u-display-none-landscape-xs
              li.menu__link.u-margin-bottom--small
                a.link-anchor <span>Telephone:</span> 
                    | 1 905 800 0000 
              li.menu__link.u-margin-bottom--small
                a.link-anchor <span>Admin Email:</span> poonam@cervinibhatia.com 
              li.menu__link
                a.link-anchor <span>Address:</span> 000 Brit Road East, 
                    | Suite Mississi, ON L00 000 
              li.menu__link
                a.link-anchor Harp Designs
```

scss code:

```
.menu{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 6;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  z-index: 10;

  background-color: #2D2D2D;

  @include element('content'){
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }

  @include element('list'){

    @include modifier('top'){
      // height: calc(70vh + 70px);
    }

    @include modifier('bottom'){
      // height: calc(30vh + 70px);

      .menu__link{
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        span{
          color: $color-offset--white;
          font-size: .9rem;
        }
        .link-anchor{
          color: $color-offset--light-grey;
          font-size: 0.8rem;
          text-transform: unset;

          &:last-of-type{
            margin-top: 10px;
            display: block;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @include element('link'){
    margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
    &:last-of-type{
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .link-anchor{
      color: $color-offset--light-grey;
      font-family: $type-font--cormorant-garamond;
      font-size: 1.7rem;
      letter-spacing: 0.175em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: all 0.6s;

      @media screen and(orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 815px){
        font-size: 1.2rem;
      }
    }
    .active{
      color: $color-offset--green;
    }
  }
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  @media only screen and(min-width: 1000px){
    width: calc(100% - 255px);
  }
}
```

This code looks great on codepen as you can see in the link but on my end.. the same code doesn't take up the full height of the menu.

Here is an image:
[image: image of what height is currently]

Also, if I set the height of .menu to 100vh then it only grows to about 75% of the height of the viewport, why does that happen? But .menu works fine if its 100% height.

Here is an image to show that as well:
[image: height: 100vh not covering whole viewport]

Comment: This may be a hack, but instead of using height, width 100% on `.menu`, remove both `width` and `height` and set `right: 0; bottom: 0`. This is a hack to force a `fixed` or `absolute` positioned element to take up entire screen.

Comment: okay thanks. Its weird.. its working now without any issues and I never changed anything. I think ever since I started using webpack.. nothing ever works right. Is there anything else to use other than webpack for a build tool.. I'm quite sick of it to be honest. I think I have spent more timing trying to use webpack than actually develop an web.

Comment: I started using Parcel.js. you can also check out Browserify

Comment: Okay thank you. I will start using parcel.js and also there is rollup. I'll give those two a shot.

Thanks once again for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS margin. Make a "DIV" tag that surrounds all of the code that you want to move up, give it an ID.

Here is the css:

## id {

margin: -50px;

}

keep playing around with the amount.

if not that, then try using padding instead.